# Different chapter name in toc, title of chapter, and header of page

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, koma-script

I am trying to use different titles and line breaks for the chapter names in toc, the chapter title itself and the header of the page. I found the following code to do that:

```
\chapter[medium-length title for TOC, if wanted]{full title name:\\ full title}
\chaptermark{short title for running headers}
```

For some reason the toc uses the title in {} instead of []. I have checked all the code and cannot figure out why something like this would happen.

I would really appreciate if there would be any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/97512)? I am not sure about the double backslash in a title...

Comment: Wild guess: Do you use a KOMA-Script class with option `headings=optiontohead`?

Comment: yes. I do use this option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a comment of the OP is mentioned that option `headings=optiontohead` is used.

KOMA-Script options `headings=optiontohead`, `headings=optiontotoc` and `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` activate the advanced functionality of the optional argument of the sectioning commands. If no key is used inside the optional argument then it only sets the header entry (`optiontohead`), the entry in ToC (`optiontotoc`) or both header and ToC entry (`optiontoheadandtoc`). But if one of this options is set, you can also use the keys `tocentry`, `head` and `reference` to get different entries in header and in TOC and with commands like `\nameref`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[%
  tocentry={medium-length title for TOC, if wanted},
  head={short title for running headers},
  reference={short title for reference}
  ]{full title name:\\ full title}\label{chap:example}
\lipsum
\chapter[short title for running headers]{full title name in text and TOC}
\lipsum
\chapter[tocentry={medium-length title for TOC, if wanted}]{full title name in text and head}
\lipsum
\bigskip
Example for reference: \nameref{chap:example}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solves the issue. Thank you so much. Impressive how you could come up with this solution with so little information.

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class provides this.

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
% ...
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[toc-title][header-title]{body-title}
\section[toc-title][header-title]{body-title}
%...
\end{document}
```

If no optional arguments are given then `body-title` is used for the ToC, header, and in the body; with one optional argument then it is used for the ToC and header and `body-title` for the body; with two optional arguments then the first (`toc-title`) is used for the ToC, the second, `header-title`, is used for the header and `body-title` for the body.